# Why does mvvmcross close current activity when StartActivityForResult is being called?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am new to mobile cross platform development. I am using Xamarin and Mvvmcross to create an application.

The problem I am currently faced with is that when I want to make a request to turn on a Bluetooth, calling StartActivityForResult(), my active activity is closing and after clicking on the dialog activity is not shown back.

When I used this method before on a simple Xamarin.Android applicaiton it worked as expected, showing a dialog request for turning on bluetooth while activity is on the background still active.

The similar problem is also happens when I am using an Intent to start an activity for sending an e-mail via built-in mail app. After sending an e-mail I am not redirected to my application back and my application is being suspended.

Here is my method:

```
 [Activity(NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainView : MvxAppCompatActivity
    {
       ...
       protected override void OnViewModelSet()
       {
            base.OnViewModelSet();
            ...
            var bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

            if(!bluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled)
               RequestEnableBluetooth();
            ...
       }
       public void RequestEnableBluetooth()
       {
           Intent turnOnBtIntent = new       
                 Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
           StartActivityForResult(turnOnBtIntent, 0);
       }
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MvvmCross does nothing like that. It is Android that does this. It does not give you any guarantee that your Activity lives on when it goes into background, it may kill it off whenever it likes.

However, your problem is that you are using `NoHistory = true` on your `Activity` this way no one can return to this `Activity` when navigated away from it.